# Way to view a parsed file output?

Tags: java, antlr

I am Vinod and am interested to use an ANTLR v3.3 for C parser generation in a Java project and generate the parsed tree in some viewable form. I got help to write grammar from [this tutorial](https://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/antlr/antlr.html#ANTLR-Grammar-Template)

ANTLR generates lexer and parser files for the grammar but I don't exactly get how these generated files are viewed. e.g. in few examples from above article, author has generated output using ASTFrame. I found only an interpreter option in ANTLRWorks which shows some tree but it gives error if predicates are more.

Any good reference book or article would be really helpful.

Comment: user644489=Vinod....Which cipher did u use:)

Comment: I haven't gotten around to [The Definitive ANTLR](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference) book yet, but it looks good. [Language Implementation Patterns](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns) is an excellent introduction to using ANTRL for generating many kinds of languages, progressively getting more complex and more advanced along the way. Highly recommended.

Comment: @sarnold, while I agree Language Implementation Patterns is a good book, I wouldn't call it an introduction to ANTLR. Sure, a few things about ANTLR are explained, but the focus is on DSL implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one book you need:

[image]

[The Definitive ANTLR Reference: Building Domain-Specific Languages](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference).

After that, many more excellent books exist (w.r.t. DSL creation), but this is *the* book for getting started with ANTLR.

Answer (score 0):

As you saw, ANTLRWorks will print both parse trees and the AST but won't work with predicates and the C target. While not a nice picture like ANTLRWorks, this will print a text version of the AST when you pass it the root of your tree.

```
void printNodes(pANTLR3_BASE_TREE thisNode, int level)
{
  ANTLR3_UINT32 numChildren = thisNode->getChildCount(thisNode);
  //printf("Child count %d\n",numChildren);

  pANTLR3_BASE_TREE loopNode;
  for(int i=0;i<numChildren;i++)
  {
    //Need to cast since these can hold anything
    loopNode = (pANTLR3_BASE_TREE)thisNode->getChild(thisNode,i);

    //Print this node
    pANTLR3_STRING thisText = loopNode->getText(loopNode);
    for(int j=0;j<level;j++)
      printf(" ");
    printf("%s\n",thisText->chars);

    //If this node has a child
    if(loopNode->getChildCount(loopNode) > 0)
      printNodes(loopNode, level + 2);
  }
}
```